# django-autocomplete-light doesn't show 'add-another' button

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I wasted a lot of time trying to solve this problem but didn't find any solution. I wanted to use django-autocomplete-light in Admin-interface not only selecting values existing in another table but adding new values. If I use it like this:

```
class MeaningAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory( Meaning)
```

everything is Ok and I can see and use 'add-another'-button on the form, but when I use it like following:

```
class MeaningAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MeaningForm
```

'add-another'-button disappears. Does anybody know how to force get this button back in the 2nd case?

Comment: I have the same problem...